# Sorting properties of an AD-object via Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get the groups an ActiveDirectory Computer-Object belongs to sorted. To get the group listing I use the following code (in this case for `PC123`):

```
Get-adcomputer 'PC123' -properties Memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf
```

I get the following output and as expected the groups are not sorted:

```
CN=(A) Group3,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=(A) Group1,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=(A) Group4,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=(A) Group2,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local
```

I tried to sort using [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.2):

```
Get-adcomputer 'PC215' -properties Memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | Sort-Object -Property Memberof
```

Unfortunately the output stays the same. I tried fooling around a bit by changing the position of `Sort-Object -Property Memberof` but that does not seem to be the problem. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf`

Comment: @Olaf this gets ridd of the enclosure (thanks for that), but the list still isn't sorted

Comment: but getting rid of the `-Property Memberof` parameter for `Sort-Object`, did the trick, why is that?

Comment: I got it...  I missunderstood the pipe. It takes the "output" from the left side of the pipe and applies the command on the right side. @Olaf feel free to post an answer if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to sort an `array` based on a property (`MemberOf`) that is not there anymore, in this case you should **not** use `-Property`.

Using this object as example:

```
$computer = [pscustomobject]@{
    Name     = 'PC215'
    MemberOf = @(
        'CN=(A) Group3,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local'
        'CN=(A) Group1,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local'
        'CN=(A) Group4,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local'
        'CN=(A) Group2,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local'
    )
}
```

```
PS /> $computer | Select-Object -Expand MemberOf | Sort-Object -Property MemberOf

CN=(A) Group3,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=(A) Group1,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=(A) Group4,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=(A) Group2,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local

PS /> $computer | Select-Object -Expand MemberOf | Sort-Object

CN=(A) Group1,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=(A) Group2,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=(A) Group3,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=(A) Group4,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local
```

---

Worth adding this quote from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.2#description) since it's related to the question:

> If sort properties are not included in a command, PowerShell uses default sort properties of the first input object. If the type of the input object has no default sort properties, PowerShell attempts to compare the objects themselves.

Comment: yeah, thank you, just figured out myself that I missunderstood the pipe symbol. Thanks a lot though for your explanation! I'll give olaf a chance to write one since he was first to answer. Otherwise I accept yours.

Comment: On a different note, why do you use the `samAccountName` isn't that just for the local accounts (as far as I remember)?

Comment: @Albin I saw his comment after posting the answer hehe, as far as I know all AD Objects have a `samAccountName` or at least computers do

Comment: Interesting, according to [here](https://www.windows-active-directory.com/windows-security-account-manager.html) the DC should store it in the AD database not the SAM, but this is all hypothetical anyway...  so never mind.

Comment: @Albin see [example 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adcomputer?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-1--get-specific-computer-that-shows-all-properties) for reference, search for the property. In any case, I'll update it on my question to avoid confusions hehe