# Sorting of multiple AD-object attributes via Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to get a computer list from the AD with the groups the computers are members in. So far fairly easy:

```
Get-adcomputer -filter * -properties Memberof | Sort CanonicalName | select-object -Property Name, Memberof
```

Works fine but the problem is that the groups (members of attribute `Memberof`) are being listet unsorted and the sorting is inconsistent from object to object.

```
Name      Memberof                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
----      --------  
PC001     {CN=(A) Group3,OU=OU-Path,DC=domain,DC=local, CN=(A) Group1,OU=OU-Path,DC=domain,DC=local, CN=(A) Group4,OU=OU-Path,DC=domain,DC=local, CN=(A) Group2,OU=OU-Path,DC=domain,DC=local}
PC002     {CN=(A) Group4,OU=OU-Path,DC=domain,DC=local, CN=(A) Group3,OU=OU-Path,DC=domain,DC=local, CN=(A) Group2,OU=OU-Path,DC=domain,DC=local, CN=(A) Group3,OU=OU-Path,DC=domain,DC=local}
PC003     ...
```

I tried to get things sorted out based on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70455444/sorting-properties-of-an-ad-object-via-powershell) using `-ExpandProperty MemberOf` e.g. somthing like this:

```
Get-adcomputer -filter * -properties Memberof | Sort CanonicalName | select-object -Property Name -ExpandProperty MemberOf | Sort-Object -Property MemberOf
```

Which I'm not surprised, did not work. Is is that possible in that manner or do I have to read out the Name and the MemberOf into separate variables and combine them again afterwards (and how do I make sure they "allign")? What would be a working approach?

Comment: `CanonicalName` is 1 element and `MemberOf` is an array, what would be the purpose of sorting your object this way?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon it's for manual comparison which is not possible if the groups are not sorted, note that I don't use the CanonicalName as an output it's just used for sorting the List

Comment: As a side note, yes I do output it in a file using `| Out-File "C:\TEMP\AD_export.txt" -Width 2000` but this is just so it doesn't cut the group list as it does in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way around this would be to construct a new object altogether however I don't see the point on doing this other than displaying the objects on the console. If this is meant for exporting the data, this approach is pointless given that `CanonicalName` is a `string` value and `MemberOf` is an `array`:

```
$computers = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        CanonicalName = 'somedomain.com/Computers/Computer2'
        Name          = 'Computer2'
        MemberOf      = @(
            'CN=(A) Group3,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local'
            'CN=(A) Group1,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local'
            'CN=(A) Group4,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local'
            'CN=(A) Group2,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local'
        )
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        CanonicalName = 'somedomain.com/Computers/Computer1'
        Name          = 'Computer1'
        MemberOf      = @(
            'CN=(A) Group3,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local'
            'CN=(A) Group1,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local'
            'CN=(A) Group4,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local'
            'CN=(A) Group2,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local'
        )
    }
)

$computers | Sort-Object CanonicalName | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Select-Object Name, @{
        Name = 'MemberOf'
        Expression = { $_.MemberOf | Sort-Object }
    }
}
```

```
Name              MemberOf
----              --------
Computer1         {CN=(A) Group1,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local, CN=(A) Group2,....
Computer2         {CN=(A) Group1,OU=OU-Path1,OU=OU-Path2,DC=domain,DC=local, CN=(A) Group2,....
```

---

If this was meant for exporting the data to, for example a CSV, this would be the approach you should take:

```
$computers | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($group in $_.MemberOf)
    {
        $cn, $ou = $group -split '(?<!\\),',2
        [pscustomobject]@{
            CanonicalName = $_.CanonicalName
            Name          = $_.Name
            MemberOf      = $cn.Replace('CN=','')
            OU            = $ou
        }
    }
} | Sort-Object CanonicalName, MemberOf | Select-Object Name, MemberOf
```

```
Name      MemberOf
----      --------
computer1 (A) Group1
computer1 (A) Group2
computer1 (A) Group3
computer1 (A) Group4
computer2 (A) Group1
computer2 (A) Group2
computer2 (A) Group3
computer2 (A) Group4
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks, I corrected the "misunderstanding" in your answer (see my answer to you comment about my question). Thanks for the extended solution to create a single list (without the sublists) that would have probable been my next question.

Comment: As a folloup questiton, is it possible to filter out the OU and DC information if possible the `CN=` as well, so all that is left under the MemberOf column is the name of the group `(A) Group1, (A) Group2, (A) Group3, ...`? But maybe it's better to write a separate question for that.

Comment: @Albin see my update, you can split the dstinguished name to get the common names of the goups. Consider accepting the answer if it was useful.

Comment: Great, thanks you as far as I understand the `OU = $ou` is not necessary for my specific output, right? (But it could come in handy if you decide you need output the OU again)

Comment: @Albin that's right, I felt it should be there if this is a report. You will want a reference of the group's OU most likely, without it you would not know which group is which if you have duplicated names.